# Kendo grid grouping questions

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I want to inplement kendo grid with grouping and have a few questions:

1. Lets say my grid is 100% height and I expand one group. Can I add a scroll to the group only and not to the entire grid??
2. Is it possible to put the collapse/expand icon of the group on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it´s not possible because what kendo does is add a new `<tr>` with the button. There is no `<div>` container to set the height and the overflow.
2. Yes you could do it. For example with this css code:

   ```
   .k-icon,
   .k-icon-collapse {
     position: relative;
     left: 100%;
   }
   ```